# JSObject: Download it or available in JRE 1.6?

Tags: java

This is a question from a Java noob.

I have eclipse open (JRE 1.6), [I have copied this code into an eclipse class](http://svn.littleshoot.org/svn/littleshoot/trunk/client/applet/src/main/java/LittleShootApplet.java).

The line in question is this:

```
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
```

Eclipse is complaining that the import can not be resolved. I read that in the docs that the Java Plug-In comes as standard and contains the above. I assumed I don't need any extra JAR files. Is this true?

Or do I need to download something to make use of JSObject?

Thanks all

Comment: The link isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Search for the `plugin.jar` normally located in your `jre\lib` folder. You will need to include that one explicitly in your eclipse project I guess

btw. don't forget to set the `MAYSCRIPT` attribute on your applet tag in order to explicitly enable java-js communication which normally is disabled by default for security reasons

Comment: Genius. I just imported that jar as an external library and it worked! No complaints from eclipse. :)

Comment: Incidentally, the current JDK7 for OS X doesn't seem to contain plugin.jar, so this answer may not work for other JDK versions.

Comment: Via CLI you can `ant build -lib /path/to/file.jar`

Comment: How do we include it?

Answer (score 0):

If in linux and you can not find the jar file (possibly using openjre) Simply copy it from a windows installation to your local linux distro and use it like you would any other jar file.

Comment: In Ubuntu you can try installing icedtea-7-plugin and take jar from there (/usr/share/icedtea-web/plugin.jar). I assume, the other distributions might have similar packages

Answer (score -3):

Javascript is just one of the ScriptEngines in JDK1.6.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/ :

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
try {
  jsEngine.eval("print('Hello, world!')");
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The question wasn't about ScriptEngines in JDK1.6 but about the JSObject which allows applets to communicate with javascript on the page the applet resides in